# localization in Bot Framework v4 with node.js - multilingual locale files

Tags: localization, botframework, locale

I have made a multilingual bot in node.js and Bot Framework v3. I have 3 locale files in json. When i change the localization settings (the language) it finds and sends the text in the correct language.

Now i would like to do the same in node.js and Bot Framework v4, but i can't find how to change the localization settings and make the same as in v3 version.

Anyone can help me to understand how the v4 works in this way?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported in Bot Framework V4 at the moment, as far as a I know.

Have a look at the [i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n) package, which you could leverage to achieve the desired behavior. You would have to set the i18n locale manually to the locale you receive from the Bot Framework. Best practice would be to do this using a middleware. `i18n.setLocale(locale);`